# Angular Overlay Positioning - How does it work?

Tags: angular, typescript, event-loop

When using the `@angular/cdk` - Overlay it produces different outcomes depending on how it's called. Whats the reasoning / mechanism behind it?

[image]

```
  showDifference() {
const amount = 3;
// left side ! NOTE: no timeout
for (let i = 1; i <= amount; i++) {
  this.show({
    text: `left ${i}`,
  }, "left")
}

// right side ! NOTE: timeout
for (let i = 1; i <= amount; i++) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.show({
      text: `right ${i}`,
    }, "right")
  }, 0)

}
```

}

The Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/mortom-toast-behavior?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftoast%2Ftoast.service.ts

Note: on the right side the `show()` method is wrapped in a timeout, meanwhile the left side is displayed without one. But only on the right-side toast positions are correctly.

Comment: Your left toasts also do not show...

Answer (score 0):

It appears what is happening is that on the left toasts, the 1st toasts is rendered, and then 2 and 3 are started before the DOM has fully updated.

Setting the timeout fixes this, but arbitrarily. You can confirm this by setting the fadeIn time to 2000 milliseconds. All 6 boxes fade in more or less at the same time / rate.

Also, It appears [the inspiration](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-toast-service) for the "toaster" didn't expect to contend with this condition. As a button click wouldn't be fast enough to cause problems.